# How do I add a calendar by URL, to a shared Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I have a URL to a calendar, which updates daily. Let's call it:

`https://example.com/calendar.ics?token=ABCDEFG`

I want to share this calendar with everyone in my organisation. However, if possible I'd like to avoid everyone having to add that URL manually to their own calendar list (and having to do it again if it changes).

What I'd like to do is import/add/merge this URL into a calendar that's already shared with my entire organisation.

That calendar would then show all events added directly to it, but also the feed of events from the URL.

Is this possible?
If so, how?